# Android xml ,2 button use minheight in a LinearLayout and 2 button is not in a line

Tags: android, xml

[image]

xml like this

```
<Linearlayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        ...../>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        ...../>

<LinearLayout/>
```

I hope the two button are aligned,but it just like the picture above.

And when I remove the minheight it works,

so any one konws why the minheight cause the right button a little down.

Comment: Your Eclipse even allows you to have a `android:weight` property?!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it without IDE and just in simplified form.Now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are using wrong properties to all views try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="40dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="40dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you， I wrote it just in simplified form.In my code,it is correct.I just want to know the influence of minheigt attribute to onlayout step in views.

Comment: @Haresh When you have 2 or more `children` inside a `LinearLayout` you should have the `orientation` property on that `LinearLayout`. Anyways, I know that the default orientation is `horizontal` but I think the property makes the code more readable.

Comment: By default LinearLayout orientation is Horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use RelativeLayout, because you have more control over the elements.

if it won't help then add  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to on of the buttons that you are happy to put on the right and then for the one which you want on the left android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/LocationIDdb" with the id of the one you set to align to the right.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to use RelativeLayout to finish this job.But now I want to know what does minHeight attribute do in onlayout(),why the view is like that (which picture i posted).